# What is the technical way to describe when you return an object/primitive that you are removing from a list in a method?

Tags: methods, return

It doesn't even necessarily need to be when you remove an object from a list, I just want to know how you would describe returning a value that is being "interacted" with (Bonus points if you can tell me what the technical phrase for "interact" is).

```
public Card deal()
{
     return deck.remove(0);
}
```

You could imagine that one would use this code to deal a card to a player's hand in a card game, calling this method within argument in an addCard() method like: `hand.addCard(deck.deal())`. I can't for the life of me figure out how to phrase this in a Google query. I'm curious to know if there is a specific word for this.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this could be called a reject if you want to remove objects from an array that the predicate does not return truthy for. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#reject

It’s the opposite of filter
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter

Comment: As I stated in the body of the inquiry, I'm not focused on the removing aspect, but rather the returning of an object/primitive that is being removed (or interacted with in any other sort of way). I'll edit my post to try to make this more clear.